# Платная подписка в приложении без активации подписки от Google

Tags: google-play

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой проблемой, подскажите, пожалуйста, легальное решение... сейчас разрабатываем приложение с платной подпиской, но мимо системы подписки от гугл.... то есть за контент приложения юзер платит картой, киви и тд непосредственно нам. как обозначать приложение на маркете? я хочу как бесплатное, но не забанит ли нас гугл ? ведь он наверняка хочет заработать на нас... да и приложение ведь реально с платной подпиской, только 14 календарных даем бесплатно....на плеймаркете я знаю приложения, которые обозначены как free, но за контент берут деньги по подписке. Меня же волнует легальность возможности брать оплату за контент мимо гугла, т.к. приложение будет международным. Спасибо!

Comment: это запрещено политикой, приложение удалят ASAP

Comment: Style-7 добрый вечер, а можно основания? я знаю приложения на гугл маркете, которые продают контент или сервис и дейстуют через подписку. Вопрос очень важный поскольку 15% отдавать гуглу ну....как то не хочется....если не 30. Ну, например, такое приложение как Muver - это софтина по подписке выключает (криво) приложения агрегаторов, когда таксист принимает заказ. Они работают напрямую без подписки гугла с 2018 года.

Comment: так для этого есть специальная статья https://play.google.com/about/monetization-ads/payments/, а "Платные услуги. Например, перевозка пассажиров и грузов, клининг, доставка еды, авиабилеты, билеты на мероприятия." под нее не попадают

Comment: Style-7вот выдержка из правил от Goggle: "Исключения составляют следующие случаи:
    продажа цифрового контента, который может использоваться вне приложения".
 То есть по факту, если мы передаем юзеру допустим GPS координаты объекта и он вызывает навигатор по ним, или передаем информацию о веб сайте, которую он открывает в браузере - это ведь и есть тот самый "цифровой контент, который может использоваться вне приложения" или нет?

Comment: Нет, вы не можете продать ссылку или координаты, а придумывать лукавые определения можно бесконечно.

Comment: Style-7 почему я не могу продать GPS координаты?? например я делаю приложение в котором я указываю точки расположения камер наблюдения на дороге, точки радаров и тд. - я сообщаю эту информацию пользователю. И беру за это деньги по подписке. Странная у вас логика....

Comment: Тоже самое с сайтами. Напимер, информация о новинках музгрупп с возможностью купить их новые альбомы прямо у них на сайте или там на амазоне. с конкретными данными - и я продаю подписку на эту информацию....

Comment: Скажем так, вы постоянно будете под дамокловым мечом, а способа заранее это узнать как гугл на это посмотрит особо нет.

Comment: Вот собственно в этом весь и вопрос. Как 100% уйти от этого меча над головой.